How to restart a GAN Training with TensorFlow 2.15 using checkpoints
I'm working on creating a Jupyter notebook for training a GAN using TensorFlow, and I want to be able to restore the last checkpoint to continue training from where I left off.
I am following this official TensorFlow tutorial. However, when I call the train() function after restoring the checkpoint, the model seems to restart from the initial state instead of continuing from the last checkpoint.
here is how I save checkpoints:
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(generator_optimizer=generator_optimizer,
                                 discriminator_optimizer=discriminator_optimizer,
                                 generator=generator,
                                 discriminator=discriminator)

here is how I restore it:
last_checkpoint_dir="/kaggle/working/training_checkpoints"
latest=tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir)
print(f"latest: {latest}")
checkpoint.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))

this is my training loop:
# Training loop
g_losses = []
d_losses = []

def train(dataset,initial_epoch=0, epochs=5):
  for epoch in range(initial_epoch, epochs, 1):
    
    start = time.time()
    
    n = dataset.cardinality() # The number of batches per epoch
    # Iterate over all batches
    batch_d_losses = []
    batch_g_losses = []
    for i, batch in enumerate(dataset):
        # Updte parameters for this batch
        g_loss, d_loss = train_step(batch)
        
        # Store losses for batch, we will average these for the whole epoch for a more stable visualization
        batch_g_losses.append(g_loss)
        batch_d_losses.append(d_loss)
        
        sys.stdout.write("\r" + "Epoch %d - batch %d of %d "%(epoch+1, i+1, n) + "[D loss: "+str(d_loss)+ " | G loss: "+str(g_loss)+"]")

    # Book-keeping:
    # Visualize losses and one example image for the epoch
    g_losses.append(np.mean(batch_g_losses))
    d_losses.append(np.mean(batch_d_losses))
    #     display.clear_output(wait=True)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    plt.title('Losses')
    xepoch = list(range(epoch+1))
    plt.plot(d_losses, label='Discriminator')
    plt.plot(g_losses, label='Generator')
    plt.legend()
    
    for image_batch in dataset:
      train_step(image_batch)


    # Save the model every 5 epochs
    if epoch % 5 == 0: # checkpoint_save_interval
      checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)
    
    # Save some example images and store model file
    if epoch % save_interval == 0:
        print('Saving epoch %d to %s'%(epoch+1, model_path))
        generator.save(os.path.join(model_path, "e%0d_generator.h5"%(epoch+1)))

    print ('Time for epoch {} is {} sec'.format(epoch + 1, time.time()-start))

    # Generate after the final epoch
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    example = generate_and_save_images(generator, epoch, seed)

I tried restoring and calling the train() function but the results of the new training seem to restart from the initial condition.
